# Pytorch LSTM grad only on last output

Tags: python, lstm, pytorch

I'm working with sequences of different lengths. But I would only want to grad them based on the output computed at the end of the sequence.

The samples are ordered so that they are decreasing in length and they are zero-padded. For 5 1D samples it looks like this (omitting width dimension for visibility):

```
array([[5, 7, 7, 4, 5, 8, 6, 9, 7, 9],
       [6, 4, 2, 2, 6, 5, 4, 2, 2, 0],
       [4, 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0],
       [8, 8, 3, 7, 7, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 7, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

For the LSTM I'm using `nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence` with the individual sequence lengths:

```
x = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(x, [10, 9, 8, 7, 5], batch_first=True)
```

The initialization of LSTM in the Model constructor:

```
self.lstm = nn.LSTM(width, n_hidden, 2)
```

Then I call the LSTM and unpack the values:

```
x, _ = self.lstm(x)
x = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(x1, batch_first=True)
```

Then I'm applying a fully connected layer and a softmax

```
x = x.contiguous()
x = x.view(-1, n_hidden)
x = self.linear(x)
x = x.reshape(batch_size, n_labels, 10) # 10 is the sample height
return F.softmax(x, dim=1)
```

This gives me an output of shape `batch x n_labels x height` (5x12x10).

For each sample, I would only want to use a single score, for the last output `batch x n_labels` (5*12). My question is How can I achieve this?

One idea is to apply `tanh` on the last hidden layer returned from the model but I'm not quite sure if that would give the same results. Is it possible to efficiently extract the output computed at the end of the sequence eg using the same lengths sequence used for `pack_padded_sequence`?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you only want to get a single output value for the whole sequence? Also, is there any reason why you need the `prelu` and linear layer? And can you show your intialization of `self.lstm`? `torch.nn.LSTMCell` basically gives you a more "barebone" implementation that also allows you to only reuse some of the outputs, e.g. the last one.

Comment: - No specific reason for Prelu, that was a mistake - I'm removing it.
- lstm initialization added
I'm looking into LSTMCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neaabfi answered `hidden[-1]` is correct. To be more specific to your question, as the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=lstm#torch.nn.LSTM) wrote:

```py
output, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm(x_pack) # batch_first = True

# h_n is a vector of shape (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)
```

In your case, you have a stack of 2 LSTM layers with only `forward` direction, then:

```py
h_n shape is (num_layers, batch, hidden_size)
```

Probably, you may prefer the hidden state `h_n` of the last layer, then **here is what you should do:

```py
output, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm(x_pack)
h = h_n[-1] # h of shape (batch, hidden_size)
y = self.linear(h)
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/quanguet/594c539b76fc52bef49ec2332e6bcd15) is the code which wraps any recurrent layer `LSTM`, `RNN` or `GRU` into `DynamicRNN`. `DynamicRNN` has a capacity of performing recurrent computations on sequences of varied lengths without any care about the order of lengths.

Comment: I ended up extracting the last output with `last_output = padded_output[np.arange(len(padded_output)), len_x-1]`

Comment: It's also the same result :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the last hidden layer as follows:

```py
output, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(x_pack)
y = self.linear(hidden[-1])
```